# Plotting multivariate continuous data

Tags: r, database, plot, continuous

I have a dataset that collected temperature on 10 different sensors each minute per three months.

I have cleaned the dataframe omitting the 'NA's and excluding other variables like air temperature, relative humidity etc... as I just want to analyse the temperature distribution across the days (see pic). I'm using R studio, version 4.2.2 "innocent and trusting"

The problem is that I have no clue how to plot this, never encountered continuous data before.

Thank you.

I have tried the hist() to obtain a gauss distribution and the most common ggplot basic functions, but I'd prefer not to share my confusion to don't confuse also who reads.

```
date    time    Temperature1    Temperature2    Temperature3    Temperature4    Temperature5    Temperature6    
2/02/2023   3:06:00 PM  37.7    34.6    34.28   37.02   34.51   35.54   40.2    36.51   35.02   34.54
2/02/2023   3:07:00 PM  NA  34.31   34.12   36.22   34.42   35.49   39.39   36.58   34.95   34.75
2/02/2023   3:08:00 PM  35.9    34.49   34.16   36.8    34.57   35.58   41.24   37.02   35.18   35.33
2/02/2023   3:09:00 PM  35.69   34.66   34.18   37.16   34.57   35.15   38.68   36.31   35.58   35.45
2/02/2023   3:13:00 PM  35.4    34.36   33.9    35.7    34.05   34.63   37.74   35.72   35.08   37.52
2/02/2023   3:14:00 PM  35.25   34.66   34.08   36.86   34.11   34.58   38.22   35.64   35.77   38.91
2/02/2023   3:15:00 PM  35.63   35.29   34.09   37.96   34.85   35.58   41.01   35.93   36.11   39.73
2/02/2023   3:16:00 PM  35.95   35.47   34.25   37.17   34.64   35.04   39.51   35.93   35.67   39.31
2/02/2023   3:17:00 PM  35.94   34.87   34.05   36.51   34.17   34.51   39.38   35.9    35.72   38.87
2/02/2023   3:20:00 PM  35.16   33.99   33.83   35.85   33.97   34.76   38.26   35.36   34.89   37.82
2/02/2023   3:21:00 PM  NA  34.22   33.77   36.99   34.34   35.37   40.31   35.86   35.31   38.51
2/02/2023   3:22:00 PM  35.31   34.28   33.74   36.34   34.03   34.76   37.72   35.43   35.26   38.61
```

Comment: We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(cleaned_data)`, if that is not too large. And it does help to see code, and any error messages.

Comment: I would typically do some variation of `library(tidyverse); df |> pivot_longer(-c(date, time)) |> mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date)) |> ggplot(aes(date, value, color = name)) + geom_line()`, or if that got too spaghetti-plotty, use facets to show each series with the others as background.